# Is it possible to change the rviz2 window title or to show the namespace used?

Tags: ros2, rviz, rqt, namespace

I am using multiple RViz2 instances simultaneously with the same configuration file but in different namespaces.
The instances are started with `ros2 run rviz2 rviz2 -d my_config.riz`

I now have a problem distinguishing the started instances because all have the same title in the window **my_config.rviz - RViz**. 
The help for Rviz (--help-all) gives the options

- `--title <title>`
- `--qwindowtitle <title>`

Unfortunately, these options have no effect.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by branching RViz2. RViz2 shows now the used namespace in the title frame. A Pull request was filed under https://github.com/ros2/rviz/pull/1073
[image]